# Is there an equivalent to layout nil in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember app that has a fairly complex application template, with an audio player, mobile drawer, header, etc. that is included in every page.

My login page needs to be able to have its own template with none of these things. In Ruby, I can simply do layout => nil to not use the application template, but I cannot find a way to do this is ember.

I don't want to just hide all the elements I am not using on this one page, nor do I want to have to explicitly include those elements on every other page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Ember.Route#renderTemplate`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate) to define [named outlets](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/) so you can dictate which outlets will connect to what view/template/mode/controller for certain routes.

For example

say I have a template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#if showTemplate}}
    <h1>App</h1>
        {{outlet center}}
        {{outlet south}}
    {{else}}
        {{outlet blank}}
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

I had an application controller like this:

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
    title: 'Cool App',
    layout: true,
    useLayout: function() {
        return this.get('layout');
    }.property('layout')
});
```

I can specify which templates I'm loading in which outlets under the application template:

```
App.LeftRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('left', {
            into: 'application',
            outlet: 'center'
        });

        this.render('south', {
            into: 'application',
            outlet: 'south'
        });
    }
});

App.RightRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('right', {
            into: 'application',
            outlet: 'center'
        });
    }
});
```

For this particular route, I set the `layout` property in the `ApplicationController` via `controllerFor`, and this will cause the application template to remove the other templates.

```
App.BlankRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        var c = this.controllerFor('application');
        c.set('layout', false);
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('blank', {
            into: 'application',
            outlet: 'blank'
        });
    }
});
```

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/KZtxW/))

With this specification, on the "right route", only the content in the "center" will be displayed, and the "south outlet" will be blank. The "blank route" will be loaded in an outlet which does not have any template markup.

I know this looks like a lot of effort, but this is just a conceptual example, which I'm sure can be improved.